# ASP.Net Webservice 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have created a webservice and i have hosted in IIS7 in my local machine and it works without any problem and canbe used within the LAN.
Then i hosted it in a paid Microsoft webserver, but once i open .asmx or anyother page on browser it gives following error message

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

My web.config is displayed below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, we'll have to see what is wrong or what is causing the error. So to get started add this line

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

under

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

in your web.config file.

Then try and load your page, it should produce a detail error message and where exactly the error is occurring i.e Which line of code

Answer (score 0):

5xx errors are internal errors, usually associated with your code or with some missing configuration in your server, since it's a paid host I would like to think it's a problem with your code, try to enable detailed error page. Add this to your web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
   </system.web>
```

Remember to change this option back when you are done debugging

Answer (score 0):

check your url (webservice address) in the ajax portion of your code.